# A Text composable that changes to a TextField on focus in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to style the content of a Text Composable that I can style conditionally, preferably with a strikethrough, but should also be an editable TextField the user can interact with.

[image]

[image]

The pictures above show the kind of effect I'm looking to get

my approach

1. use a Text composable to display the text and style with
2. when user interacts with Text Composable, change it to a TextField

challenge
the challenge is changing between the two composables programmatically

would like suggestions to go about it in a completely different way or using my approach

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using compose rich editor library
https://github.com/MohamedRejeb/Compose-Rich-Editor

You can have a styled text field using this library follow these steps:

1- Add the dependency

```
implementation("com.mohamedrejeb.richeditor:richeditor-compose:$version")
```

2- Add the Rich Text Value

```
var richTextValue by remember { mutableStateOf(RichTextValue()) }
```

3- Add the Rich Text Field

```
RichTextEditor(
    value = richTextValue,
    onValueChange = {
        richTextValue = it
    },
)
```

Now you can set the style that you want, let's say that you want the text added text to have StrikeThrough style you just need to apply that style to the `richTextValue`:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    richTextValue = richTextValue.addStyle(RichTextStyle.Strikethrough)
}
```

Note: The library still in it's early stages and it may not fill exactly your needs so you can text me in the Kotlin slack if you need to have more customization